# Spring Beginner - No such field error

Tags: spring

I am new to spring. I am developing one sample project using spring. I am getting the following exception when I provide a value in Beans.xml. Please provide solution.

Beans.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

   <bean id="helloWorld" class="com.dhr.spring.beans.HelloWorld">
       <property  name="message"  value="d" />
   </bean>

</beans>
```

HelloWorld.java:

```
public class HelloWorld {
     private String message;

       public void setMessage(String message){
          this.message  = message;
       }

       public void getMessage(){
          System.out.println("Your Message : " + message);
       }
}
```

MainApp:

```
 public class MainApp {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
          ApplicationContext context = 
                 new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");

          HelloWorld obj = (HelloWorld) context.getBean("helloWorld");

          obj.getMessage();
       }
}
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NULL
    at org.springframework.expression.TypedValue.<clinit>(TypedValue.java:31)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardEvaluationContext.setRootObject(StandardEvaluationContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardEvaluationContext.<init>(StandardEvaluationContext.java:74)
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:124)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.evaluateBeanDefinitionString(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.evaluate(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:210)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:182)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: may be some solution here - https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-1883

Comment: How did you added your spring jars to your classpath? are you using some dependency management (like maven) or manually in eclipse?

Comment: I am not using Mavan. Manually adding to the project. jars are: org.springframework.asm-3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework.beans-3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework.context-3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework.core-3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework.expression-3.0.3.RELEASE, org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework.web-3.1.0.RELEASE

Comment: use maven and add the spring dependency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome! To the ambiguous world of Spring! Where stack traces are long and documentation is <strike>short</strike> convoluted.

I have seen this error several times and, at least for me, it usually has to do with dependency inconsistencies.

I see that you just posted you are not using Maven. I can almost assure you that that is the problem. You really SHOULD be using Maven. The amount of work it will save you is monumental.

**Edit:** To make this post more answer-like: You are getting the error due to dependency inconsistencies. You are manually putting Spring JAR files into your dependency tree which is not recommended. 
Either 1) Use Maven to handle dependency management (recommended) or 2) Ensure that all your JAR files utilize non-conflicting and coherent dependency trees.

For instance, you are using `org.springframework.expression-3.0.3.RELEASE` which is not part of the `3.1.x` group. So, replace the jar file with `org.springframework.expression-3.1.0-RELEASE`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @mohacs I have updated my answer, I thought it was self-explanatory. But I appreciate the sentiment nonetheless.